# Resizing and dragging SVG polygons dynamically

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, resize

I am struggling to find a way for resizing and dragging a svg polygon dynamically with the mouse. Unfortunately jQueryUi does not work for svg elements. I also checked the Raphael library, but cant find any documentation/snippets on how to realize this.

Besides using SVGs, is there any other way to resize and dragg a polygon graphic dynamically?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can work with the SVG elements yourself. In particular, you can find the points of the polygon and add HTML-element handles which are made draggable with jQuery. (I'm assuming the problem you're having is that jQuery UI doesn't work with the SVG positioning model.) Here's a complete example I just wrote (tested in Safari 5 and Firefox 9).

(Disclaimer: I am not a regular user of jQuery; this code may be unidiomatic in ways besides not using jQuery for everything.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
  <title>untitled</title>

  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .handle {
      position: absolute;
      border: 0.1em solid black;
      width: 1em;
      height: 1em;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function draggablePolygon(polygon) {
    var points = polygon.points;
    var svgRoot = $(polygon).closest("svg");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < points.numberOfItems; i++) {
      (function (i) { // close over variables for drag call back
        var point = points.getItem(i);

        var handle = document.createElement("div");
        handle.className = "handle";
        document.body.appendChild(handle);

        var base = svgRoot.position();
        // center handles over polygon
        var cs = window.getComputedStyle(handle, null);
        base.left -= (parseInt(cs.width) + parseInt(cs.borderLeftWidth) + parseInt(cs.borderRightWidth))/2; 
        base.top -= (parseInt(cs.height) + parseInt(cs.borderTopWidth) + parseInt(cs.borderBottomWidth))/2; 

        handle.style.left = base.left + point.x + "px";
        handle.style.top = base.top + point.y + "px";

        $(handle).draggable({
          drag: function (event) {
            setTimeout(function () { // jQuery apparently calls this *before* setting position, so defer
              point.x = parseInt(handle.style.left) - base.left;
              point.y = parseInt(handle.style.top) - base.top;
            },0);
          }
        });
      }(i));
    }
  }
  </script>
</head><body>
  <p>
    (Offset to test)
    <svg id="theSVG" width="500" height="500" style="border: 2px inset #CCC;">
      <polygon id="x" points="200,200 100,100 100,1" fill="green" />
      <polygon id="y" points="200,200 100,100 1,100" fill="red" />
    </svg>
  </p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    draggablePolygon(document.getElementById("x"));
    draggablePolygon(document.getElementById("y"));
  </script>

</body></html>
```

You could also attach an event handler to the SVG polygon and implement dragging (I tested and this could work), but then you would have to click inside the current boundaries of the polygon, which is an atypical UI and possibly tricky, and implement your own hit testing.

For this, you would add an `onmousedown` handler to the polygon element. Then retrieve its points, find which is in range of the click position, store the initial mouse position, and then have an `onmousemove` handler modify the `x` and `y` of the point as the mouse position changes.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I am working on the dragging - clicking inside the boundaries is exactly what I want.

Also I am trying to label these polygons with svg-text, but i didnt figured out how to update the text position, while resizing the polygon. Can you give any hint??

Comment: Sure, I added a hint. Unfortunately I didn't save the code I wrote first.

Comment: Hey, I am facing the problem, that I need the updated coordinates of the polygon as I'm resizing it. When I inspect a resized polygon element with firebug, it still has the old points in it, although it was resized. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: The `polygon.points` object should have the new coordinates; my code has examples of accessing it.

Comment: props to huge answer AND tech support :)

Comment: `You could also attach an event handler to the SVG polygon and implement dragging (I tested and this could work)` - any chance of posting the code?