# Draw polygons on existing SVG to capture coordinate data

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

We have a web application that displays a SVG map of an office. The map has small icons that represent users walking around with RF tags. This allows administrators of the system to see what rooms users are in. We are using [Snap.SVG](http://snapsvg.io/) to load the office SVG file and manipulate it to display the user icons. The challenge is that the map scales to the size of the browser. Using JavaScript to determine the coordinates is not always accurate because the position of the SVG changes based on the browser size.

Here is an example of the map with the icons:
[image: Location SVG Map]

The icons are placed on the map based on X Y coordinates coming from our database. The values for the X Y coordinates are set for each location and were determined using Adobe Illustrator. Currently, we can only place one icon in a room at a time. Because we only have 1 set coordinates the icons overlap if more than one person is in a room at one time.

The second phase of this project is to allow users to draw on of the map to specify locations. Essentially, the user will set points and create a polygon to represent each location on the map. We would use the coordinates of the polygon along with the total area of the polygon to know where on the map we can place icons. This would allow users to define areas without a developer getting involved.

Here is an example of what we want to achieve . 
[image: Rendering of what we want to achieve]

I have been researching how to do this, but have not found anything outside of using something like the Google Maps API to draws polygons on a map. I did find this [article that outlines how to dynamically pull points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945134/resizing-and-dragging-svg-polygons-dynamically). We thought about using a grid system that is an overlay on the map and the user defines what grid elements are in what locations. So something like [A1,A2,B1,B2]. I persoanlly like the polygon approach as it is more visually appealing and is easier for a user to adopt.

We need some advice on where to start with this and if something like snap.svg is all we need or if we have to rely on other libraries in conjunction with snap.

**Update:**

With Ian's advice I found a fiddle that describes what he was talking about.

```
var S;
var pt;
var svg
var box;

window.onload = function(){
    svg = $('#mysvg')[0];
    S = Snap(svg);
    console.log( S );

    pt = pt = svg.createSVGPoint(); // create the point

    // add the rectangle
    box = S.rect(12,12, 12, 12);
    box.attr({ fill : 'red', stroke : 'none' });

    S.drag(
        function(dx, dy, posX, posY, e){

            //onmove
            pt.x = posX - S.node.offsetLeft;
            pt.y = posY - S.node.offsetTop;
            console.log(pt.x + "," + pt.y);

            // convert the mouse X and Y 
            //so that it's relative to the svg element
            var transformed = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getCTM().inverse());
            box.attr({ x : transformed.x, y : transformed.y });
        },
        function(){
            //onstart
        },
        function(){
            //onend
        }
    );

}
```

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddivita/59mhd5yh/)

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand the problem with creating polygons, and why a grid system is needed. Can you not just have click handlers and figure out a coordinate from the mouse event and build up a polygon from there ? I'm probably not quite understanding something though.

Comment: @Ian, I updated the question. The image scales with the browser so determining the actual position is a challenge. if the image was always the same and in the same position, this would not be an issue.

Comment: I think you'd just need to account for the screen matrix on the scaled element, relative to the screen coordinates of the mouse event.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Also, the fiddle is broken - the console says 'TypeError: Value being assigned to SVGPoint.x is not a finite floating-point value.'

Comment: @MatthewCornell, the fiddle seems to work fine. I did find a solution and have been planning to post it here. We are using static polygons created in Adobe Illustrator and placing them in the map. This way each section will have its own polygon and we can stay within the bounds of each polygon